# Close inactive connections in Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I'm running a Twisted server with the LineReceiver protocol.  Sometimes clients will disconnect silently, so Twisted keeps the connection open.  And because the server doesn't send anything unless requested of it, there's never a TCP timeout.  In other words, some connections are never closed server-side.

How can I have Twisted close a connection that's been inactive for a few hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can schedule timed events using `reactor.callLater`.  Based on this, there's a helper for adding timeouts to protocols, `twisted.protocols.policies.TimeoutMixin`.

Another approach is to use TCP keep-alives, which you can enable using the transport's `setTcpKeepAlive` method.

And another approach is to use application-level keep-alives.  Essentially send a ''noop'' once in a while.  It doesn't need a response.  If the connection has been lost, the extra data in the send buffer will cause the TCP stack to eventually notice.

See also the [FAQ entry](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#WhyisntmyconnectionLostmethodcalled).

Comment: Can we change the default timeout value to another value ?

Comment: Which default timeout?  Your operating system may allow you to configure TCP keepalive on a global basis but it's probably not a great idea to go messing with that.  Twisted's TCP support doesn't add any additional timeout logic on top of TCP itself.  If you want such logic, that's what `TimeoutMixin` and `reactor.callLater` are for.