# Twisted close web server connection

Tags: python, twisted

Im writing a simple web server application using twisted. The application will get a  string and return the reverse of the string it received.

It all works fine. Now I need to close the socket connection if there is an inactivity for 5 mins.

Here is my server code:-

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol


class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    """This is just about the simplest possible protocol"""

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        "As soon as any data is received, write it back."
        self.transport.write(data[::-1])


def main():
    """This runs the protocol on port 8000"""
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = Echo
    reactor.listenTCP(8000,factory)
    reactor.run()

# this only runs if the module was *not* imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
~
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11911453/892383

Answer (score 1):

Add these methods to your class:

```
def connectionMade(self):
    def terminate():
        self.terminateLater = None
        self.transport.abortConnection()
    self.terminateLater = reactor.callLater(60 * 5, terminate)

def connectionLost(self, reason):
    delayedCall = self.terminateLater
    self.terminateLater = None
    if delayedCall is not None:
        delayedCall.cancel()
```

This makes it so that when a connection is established, your protocol will scheduled a timed call in 5 minutes to close the connection.  If the connection is closed otherwise, it will cancel the timeout.